# Odoo functions from parent

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have made a qweb report for res.partner that should list all the projects for that customer. But i don't know how to take the id for the current res.partner so i can search the database. I want to do something like the following code(where self.id is the id for the current partner):

```
data = self.env['project.project'].search([('partner_id', '=', self.id)])
```

I want to return the current open contact. For example if i call the function from the contact menu of Delta PC, i want the id of the contact Delta PC.
I have tried someting like this:

```
partner = self.env['res.users'].browse(self.env.uid).partner_id
```

but it returns the current logged user from the contacts table.

Comment: In which model are you writing that line? If you print `self` there, what do you see in the log?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<span t-esc="env.user.partner_id.name"/>
```

Following code will print current partner logged in.